# Outlook 2013 does not send emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

I installed the Office Home and Business 2013 package (32-bit) on my new Dell (64-bit). Word, Excel and Powerpoint work fine but Outlook 2013 is a disaster. I can receive emails but not send. It also does not accept my 2010 Outlook.pst file. I checked with my ISP and email server administrator and they both say there is no problem on their side. All the settings are correct. When I send a test email Outlook says that all was successful but the email is never sent!

I was advised to try installing Outlook 2010 which I did. I installed it but when I want to run it I get the error message – "The operating system is not presently configured to run this application."

Can I have both 2010 and 2013 Outlook installed at the same time? If not, how do I get rid of Outlook 2013 if it was installed as a package?

I was thinking of just wiping everything out and installing Office 2010 or using a different email package such as Pegasus mail but I do not know if that will read my Outlook.pst file.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Are you sure your running a 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: Yes, it says so on the OEM package and when I go into the computor's properties.

Comment: @Patrick Which OS are you using, Windows 7 or 8 or 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you might have a corrupted Outlook 2013 file.
Try reinstalling 2013 - make sure that when it's uninstalled that all elements are uninstalled. Restart your computer after the uninstall. Do not reinstall the 2010.pst until you test the sending function.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding connectivity problem**

Well, another possibility is firewall or some kind internet security app such as Kaspersky Internet Security - it's posible that it detects that Outlook executable is changed and trying to block it.
Try to turn it off (if any) for some time and see what happends.

**Regarding Outlook 2010 .pst file**

It may be corrupted. Try to use C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\SCANPST.exe
to repair it first - than try again
Please note - this tool rarely works from the first time - You need use it few times in the row